# Youtube Data API retrieve channel subscribers count for past dates

Tags: java, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube-data-api

i know that we can pull the current number of subscribers for a youtube channel using the data API, but is there a way to pull the subscribers we had in the past? for example 7 days back?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like a good thing to check the docs for: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Subscriptions Also it doesn't appear they support doing that.

Comment: yeah i did check the docs but could not find a thing about this.. I just wanted to know if anyone have ever tried to pull that info or knows about a workaround to this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in way to do a historic look at your subscribers. What you could do is retrieve your list of subscribers on a given date, and persist it yourself somewhere. Then do it again next week and compare it.

The API returns a JSON response & the look up would look like this:

> https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet&mySubscribers=true&key={API_KEY_GOES_HERE}

You can read more here about the syntax & parameters in the docs: [Link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list)

Comment: yeah i think that would be the only possible workaround for now.. perhaps (hopefully) yt team would include that feature in a future release of the api. Thanks MagicMan.