# Is there a way to get historical youtube subscriber information?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

Currently I am retrieving daily subscriber information with the following request:

```
var videoOptions = {
        'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
        'id': videoIds
    };

    // Send request
    youtube.videos.list(videoOptions, (err, videoDetails) => {});
```

My question is there a way to get historical subscriber information either through the Data API or Analytics API?

I see there is a way to see subs gained or lost over a period of time but I don't know what the base is to compare against:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3D{channelID}&start-date=2017-07-31&end-date=2017-08-01&&metrics=subscribersLost%2CsubscribersGained
```

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to retrieve the historical number of subscribers in the past. The only way you can track your subscriber change is to perform [channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#try-it), setting mySubscribers property to true and do it the next day. No method to check for history. This is also confirmed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21176432/youtube-data-api-retrieve-channel-subscribers-count-for-past-dates).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how large your subscriber base is, you could try checking the list of when users started subscribing at https://www.youtube.com/subscribers
Perhaps this can offer some insight, and the number of rows/users returned can be counted to give an indication of historical activity.