# Is there a way to get the subscriber count of two particular users of youtube from their beginning of career to the most recent possible?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to plot a graph of their subscriber growth overtime against one another, how can one do that using python and youtube data API?
I am looking to plot their graphs against each other to demonstrate subscriber growth and downfall over the span of their careers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get historical youtube subscriber information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578222/is-there-a-way-to-get-historical-youtube-subscriber-information)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless the answer has changed from 2017 this is a duplicate of this question [Is there a way to get historical youtube subscriber information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45578222/7838574)

From what I can tell the data isn’t available from YouTube: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list